# NOT FOUND on not existing id in database passed as url param

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I have the following controller:

```
@PostMapping("/product/{id}")
void getProduct (@PathVariable UUID productId);
```

and `id` is id from my database table. My ORM is Hibernate. How to return `NOT_FOUND` if there is no such `id` in the best way?
I know that I can:

```
void getProduct(@PathVariable UUID productId){
    // check whether exists a file and throw NOT_FOUND if not.
}
```

I am looking better method to do it- it is very common situation in my project.

Answer (score 1):

A very common and effective pattern to you problem is the following where the service layer delegates the database not found case to an application specific exception and then a controller advisor handles the exception translation to a meaningful rest response. [This](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) is an old article @ spring.io which will give you even more suggestions.

The service bean:

```
@Service
class ResourceService {

  @Autowired
  ResourceDao dao;

  Resource getById(UUID id) {
    Resource res = dao.findById(id);
    if (res != null) {
      throw new MyNotFoundException();
    }
    return res;
  }

}
```

The advisor bean:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = MyNotFoundException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(MyNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
        String bodyOfResponse = "No resource with this id found.";
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, bodyOfResponse, 
          new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, request);
    }
}
```